# How to change the target version of android in android studio

Tags: android

I import an eclipse project into my android studio. The original project's target is android-14, but my studio's mimimum API version is 21. And I don't want to download the API 14, how should solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You only must have downloaded the SDK configured as `compileSdkVersion`. Your SDK configured as `minSdkVersion` can be a lower version such as API 14.

In the Android Studio the configuration is realized in `build.grade` file. For example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(":lib")
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Actually, my build.gradle's content is more simpler than the example you show me. And I don know reason. So I just new an android studio project, and I copy the java files and res. I don't know how to describe my problem and show build.gradle code, but still thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add dependencies in build.gradle to use 
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"